# ASP Core API 2.2. RequireClaim and RequireAuthenticatedUser policies are not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

ASP CORE 2.2 API. I have 2 policies :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireClientClaim", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim("Client"));
                options.AddPolicy("AllAuthenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });
```

"RequireClientClaim" does not allow any users even with Client claim. Claims are taken from database and added to JWT token. Token is sent back with authorization: Bearer xxxx header. I can see this claim in next request from user in context.HttpContext.User.Claims: 
[image]

"AllAuthenticated" allows everyone :) So I guess something is very broken here.

```
    [HttpPost, Route("refresh")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "AllAuthenticated")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ActionName(){}
```

I did not put any policies in Filters since my policies are not intended to be applied to all controllers and actions.
Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;
using Scrutor;
using MediatR;
using System.Reflection;
using xxxxxxx.Features.shared;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AspNetCore.Identity.Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using ConnectionsManager;

namespace xxxxxx
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddNodeServices(options =>
            {
                options.ProjectPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "App");                
            });

            services.AddLazyCache();

            services.AddResponseCompression();
            services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
           {
               options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest;
           });

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                            ValidIssuer = null,
                            ValidAudience = null,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxxxxxxxx"))
                        };
                    });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().Build();
                });
            });            
            var connectionString = DbConnectionsManager.GetConnectionStringToSqlDB();
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {                
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789, -._@+ñÑçÇäëïöüâêîôûáéíóúàèìòùÄËÏÖÜÂÊÎÔÛÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙ";
            });
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                    .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
                    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
                    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                    .AddDapperStores(connectionString)
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc(config => 
                {
                  config.Filters.Add<CurrentUserFilter>();
                  config.Filters.Add(new UserLanguageFilter());                    
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

            services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireClientClaim", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim("Client"));
                options.AddPolicy("AllAuthenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "App/dist";
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "XXXXXXXXX", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.Scan(scan => scan
             .FromAssembliesOf(typeof(SapViewsProxyDBLoaders.SimilarItemsSapViewLoader)) 
               .AddClasses()       
                 .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip) 
                 .AsImplementedInterfaces()    
                 .WithSingletonLifetime());


            services.Scan(scan => scan
              .FromCallingAssembly() 
                .AddClasses()        
                  .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip) 
                  .AsImplementedInterfaces()    
                  .WithTransientLifetime()); 


            services.Scan(scan => scan
              .FromAssembliesOf(typeof(SapDataProvider.SapDataProvider),
              typeof(ConnectionsManager.SapConfiguration),              
              typeof(FeaturesLogs.Products.PriceRequestLogger)) 
                .AddClasses()        
                  .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip) 
                  .AsImplementedInterfaces()    
                  .WithTransientLifetime());

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseResponseCompression();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");                
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSwagger();            
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "xxxx");
            });

            var defaultDateCulture = "es-ES";
            var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

            // Configure the Localization middleware
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    ci,
                },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    ci,
                }
            });

            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirect("index.html", "/"));

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {                
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
                    {
                        options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.js";
                        options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
                                ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr")
                                : null;
                        options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };

                    });
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you executing the code in the photo?

Comment: @johnny5 in one of custom filters in `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of `RequireClaim` should be `claimType` :

```
public AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireClaim(string claimType, params string[] requiredValues);
```

If you want to restrict the `client` value which is role(`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`) type , the policy will like :

```
options.AddPolicy("RequireClientClaim", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Client"));
```